# 11.10 suddenly became 2d

Tags: 11.10, 2d

After today's update ubuntu became 2d despite the fact that I logged in under "ubuntu" not "ubuntu 2d".
Also some other issues appeared (e.g. my shortcuts rolled back, num pad doesn't work, caps lock key don't have any effect on case, when I'm typing in dash - it doubles every letter - 'n' --> 'nn' )

Here is update log:

```
Setting up google-chrome-stable (17.0.963.83-r127885) ...
Setting up libavutil51 (4:0.8.1-1~ppa1) ...
Setting up libpostproc52 (4:0.8.1-1~ppa1) ...
Setting up libswscale2 (4:0.8.1-1~ppa1) ...
Setting up libavcodec53 (4:0.8.1-1~ppa1) ...
Setting up libavformat53 (4:0.8.1-1~ppa1) ...
Setting up libbluray1 (1:0.2.2-1~ppa1) ...
Setting up libmp3lame0 (3.99.5+repack1-3~ppa1) ...
Setting up libx264-120 (2:0.120.2171+git01f7a33-3~ppa1) ...
Setting up libxvidcore4 (2:1.3.2-9~ppa1) ...
Setting up thunderbird (11.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apport/blacklist.d/thunderbird ...
Setting up thunderbird-globalmenu (11.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-gnome-support (11.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en (1:11.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en-gb (1:11.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en-us (1:11.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-ru (1:11.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-tweak (0.6.2-1~oneiric1) ...
Setting up xul-ext-calendar-timezones (1.3+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up xul-ext-lightning (1.3+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up xul-ext-gdata-provider (1.3+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
```

Here is .xsession-errors file first line:

```
gnome-session[6568]: WARNING: Session 'ubuntu' runnable check failed: Exited with code 1
```

Any ideas?
I can provide the rest of file, but it pretty long

Comment: From what I can see, `ubuntu-tweak` was updated. Perhaps that may have rendered some of your issues that you are having. Try checking the settings on `ubuntu-tweak`.

Comment: I checked them, but what unusual should I look for? Everything looks normal...Tomorrow I'll try to reset unity and gnome to default settings, hope it will help, but I doubt. Btw I found new issue - when I'm typing in dash - it doubles every letter - 'n' --> 'nn' O.o Seems my os becoming completely mad.

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve the update logs, simply run the following command:

`$ gedit /var/log/apt/term.log`

Then scroll to the bottom to view the latest updates installed on your computer and any errors if you have any.